# meetup vs. meet-up

Tags: meaning, hyphens

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/meet-up), "meetup" and "meet-up" are one and the same, but isn't true that when there's a hyphen between two words, in this case "meet-up", it's an adjective and not a noun?

> meetup or meet-up -
> a meeting, especially a regular meeting of people who share a particular interest and have connected with each other through a social-networking website

Comment: Hyphenation is not hard and fast in English, but in general style guides will advise verbs without ("let's meet up") and noun with ("The meet-up is cancelled").  There is a distinct tendency to solidify common words ("The meetup is cancelled").

Comment: It is generally only in American English that “meet-up” (or “meet up”) is used as a noun, as you have used it here. I only see “meet up” used as a phrasal verb in Australian English, with “meeting” being the corresponding noun. I believe the same is true of British English.

Comment: 19000 views and not one u[vote or downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we use "meet-up" when used as a noun and "meet up" when used as a verb, e.g.

> Let's **meet up** at the cafe for a short discussion.

> We need to have a **meet-up** for a conference.

Or even (commonly):

> We need to have a **meetup** for a conference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations and I am so sorry for the very late response!

Comment: I have one more question ... ¿Is there an adjective for "meet-up"? Thank you!